# how to reserve a symbol for number sign in java printf?

Tags: java, formatting, printf, double

I need a help in formatting double in the printf method. A function display ArrayList of double (2 numbers in one row)
Numbers might have different symbols. So how can I reserve a space for the symbol?
I tried

```
printf(%02.2f \t %02.2f\n);
```

If we have 1.1 and 3.1 in the next row - it's ok. But when it's  -1.1 and 3.1 the second number stand left for one symbol.

Is there any symbol in printf to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("% 01.2f \t % 02.2f\n", -1.1, 3.1);
```